# Testing 'UCM'-VOB performance

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Our VOB's currently have the feature level 5 and I'm tasked with upgrading to level 9 and making sure that everything still works. I've already read the technote [from IBM](http://%20https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/73065) about feature levels.

For feature level 7 it states:

> Improved UCM performance

I somehow want to put this into numbers. Can someone give me a broad overview on how I could achieve that. Im relatively new to ClearCase and prior to ClearCase I only knew git so I would be thankful for some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu can find concrete criteria for measuring UCM performance in:

- the whitepaper "[Component Organization and UCM Performance](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/517_ucm/component_scaling.pdf)" ([**Richard Curtis**](https://twitter.com/lookatrichc), David Qiang Li)
- the [feature levels](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/about-feature-levels-and-clearcase) (similar to what you have seen)

From the first paper, you can derive the setup configuration:

> Our test environment consisted of a VOB server host and a fixed number of clients connected by a 100MB full-duplex network.
>
> The VOB server hosted one PVOB and one component VOB.
> The component VOB was created initially with a single, root-level component.
> In subsequent tests, the component VOB was created with one or more sub-VOB components.
>
> The number of elements (32,768) remained constant, regardless of the number of components.

And the commands which are measured.

Non-UCM commands in UCM views:

- `checkout file`
- `checkin file`
- `setact activity_name`
- `setact -none`
- `mkelem file`

UCM commands for developers:

- `diffbl -ver`
- `deliver -pre -l -str -to`
- `deliver -str -to -f`
- `deliver -com -f`
- `rebase -rec -view`
- `rebase -com`

UCM commands for project managers:

- `chstream -rec`
- `diffbl -act`
- `mkbl -inc`

UCM commands for release engineer:

- `rebase -rec`
- `rebase -com`
- `mkbl -full -ide -com`

Once you have an environment, and a script with those commands, you can run said scripts a few time *before* the feature level upgrade, then run the same script after, and measure the execution time delta.

Comment: Also, just as a note, Feature Level 7 is the first feature level that REQUIRES schema version 80. One of the key hallmarks of Schema 80 is that the UCM objects (baselines, activities, streams, etc.) have discrete record types. Once FL7 is enabled, CC makes better use of them...

Comment: @BrianCowan Good point. I remember at the time having to deal with schema 54 to 80 migration (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/clearcase-80-vob-schema-80-and-feature-level-7-migration-strategies)